# Is there a way to integrate a Google Form into an Android Application?

Tags: android, google-forms

I have a couple forms already created on Google Forms and I'm wondering if there is a way to load it into an Android app I am creating.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use a `WebView` and set the load url to your Google Forms url. For more information please visit the [Google's official documentation on WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

The following link walks through creating a google form, getting the url and keys from it to then programmatically obtain data from the android app.

http://codesmith.in/post-data-google-drive-sheet-through-mobile-app

This worked for me, hope it helps. :)

Comment: Please try and include the relevant content from the link in your post. Over time, the link can die - which will render your answer useless.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/FoamyGuy/GoogleFormUploadExample

GoogleFormUploadExample

If you are just interested in integrating with forms, and don't care too much about the details of how it works I suggest using the [GoogleFormUploader] 1 Library that I have created. This project will give you the "behind the scenes look" at how it works. Whereas the library will give you a cleaner API to accomplish the same task.

Example Android application that demonstrates how to upload some data into a Google form/spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

I followed @user5404864 solution's and it was not working, and I saw few other people with similar solutions just using different ways to send, like using Volley, so I was thinking maybe recently Google stop allowing people to send it, why can't I send it? And checking the log there was some misleading responses form the server and well debugging a bit dipper found an error 401 that means we have a problem with authentication... because I already had spent many hours trying this I thought well let me give a last try, let's remove everything that would require authorization, i.e let allow someone to answer anonymously so I just uncheck the box to let the user to edit the response and to only respond once:

[image: Google form settings]

Then the solution presented by @user5404864 worked just fine.